# PHP DOMDocument loadHTML not encoding UTF-8 correctly

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to parse some HTML using DOMDocument, but when I do, I suddenly lose my encoding (at least that is how it appears to me).

```
$profile = "<div><p>various japanese characters</p></div>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($profile); 

$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach ($divs as $div) {
    echo $dom->saveHTML($div);
}
```

The result of this code is that I get a bunch of characters that are not Japanese.  However, if I do:

```
echo $profile;
```

it displays correctly.  I've tried saveHTML and saveXML, and neither display correctly. I am using PHP 5.3.

What I see:

```
ã¤ãªãã¤å·ã·ã«ã´ã«ã¦ãã¢ã¤ã«ã©ã³ãç³»ã®å®¶åº­ã«ã9äººåå¼ã®5çªç®ã¨ãã¦çã¾ãããå½¼ãå«ãã¦4äººãä¿³åªã«ãªã£ããç¶è¦ªã¯æ¨æã®ã»ã¼ã«ã¹ãã³ã§ãæ¯è¦ªã¯éµä¾¿å±ã®å®¢å®¤ä¿ã ã£ããé«æ ¡æä»£ã¯ã­ã£ãã£ã®ã¢ã«ãã¤ãã«å¤ãã¿ãæè²è³éãåããªããã«ããªãã¯ç³»ã®é«æ ¡ã¸é²å­¦ã
```

What should be shown:

```
イリノイ州シカゴにて、アイルランド系の家庭に、9人兄弟の5番目として生まれる。彼を含めて4人が俳優になった。父親は木材のセールスマンで、母親は郵便局の客室係だった。高校時代はキャディのアルバイトに勤しみ、教育資金を受けながらカトリック系の高校へ進学
```

EDIT: I've simplified the code down to five lines so you can test it yourself.

```
$profile = "<div lang=ja><p>イリノイ州シカゴにて、アイルランド系の家庭に、</p></div>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($profile);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
echo $profile;
```

Here is the html that is returned:

```
<div lang="ja"><p>ã‚¤ãƒªãƒŽã‚¤å·žã‚·ã‚«ã‚´ã«ã¦ã€ã‚¢ã‚¤ãƒ«ãƒ©ãƒ³ãƒ‰ç³»ã®å®¶åº­ã«ã€</p></div>
<div lang="ja"><p>イリノイ州シカゴにて、アイルランド系の家庭に、</p></div>
```

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580543/php-japanese-strings-getting-set-to

Comment: Thanks.  I checked all those and nothing helped.  I don't get ????, but some other strange text.  I'll try to paste it here, but don't know how the site will display it.

Comment: Try using [utf8_encode](http://php.net/utf8_encode)

Comment: Tried with no success.  Returned the same characters as before.

Answer (score 696, accepted):

`DOMDocument::loadHTML` will treat your string as being in ISO-8859-1 (the HTTP/1.1 default character set) unless you tell it otherwise. This results in UTF-8 strings being interpreted incorrectly.

DOMDocument uses an HTML4 parser. If you're loading HTML5, you might want to look at [alternative solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712503/how-to-make-html5-work-with-domdocument).

If you're dealing with simple snippets of (X)HTML, you could prepend an XML encoding declaration or a meta charset declaration to cause the string to be treated as UTF-8:

```php
$profile = '<p>イリノイ州シカゴにて、アイルランド系の家庭に、9</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();

// This version preserves the original characters
$contentType = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">';
$dom->loadHTML($contentType . $profile);
echo $dom->saveHTML();

// This version will HTML-encode high-ASCII bytes
$dom->loadHTML('<meta charset="utf8">' . $profile);
echo $dom->saveHTML();

// This version will also HTML-encode high-ASCII bytes,
// and won't work for LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION >= 2.12.0
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $profile);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

If you cannot know if the HTML will already contain declarations, there's a workaround in [SmartDOMDocument](http://beerpla.net/projects/smartdomdocument-a-smarter-php-domdocument-class/) which should help you:

```php
$profile = '<p>イリノイ州シカゴにて、アイルランド系の家庭に、9</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($profile, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

In PHP 8.2+, you'll get a deprecation warning, so the alternative would be:

```php
$profile = '<p>イリノイ州シカゴにて、アイルランド系の家庭に、9</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_encode_numericentity($profile, [0x80, 0x10FFFF, 0, ~0], 'UTF-8'));
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

*(For a better explanation of that rather cryptic array, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854535/better-explanation-of-convmap-in-mb-encode-numericentity).)*

This is not a great workaround, but since not all characters can be represented in ISO-8859-1 (like these katana), it's the safest alternative.

Comment: Tried with no success.  Also, UTF-8 is the default for the constructor in PHP5, so should not be necessary, anyway.

Comment: Yes, that did it.  Thank you for your help.  I tried saveHTML, saveXML, didn't think that the problem may have been coming during the load.

Comment: The mb_convert_encoding call worked for me, whereas prepending the encoding declaration didn't. Likely because the document already had a conflicting declaration. Many thanks - saved me a lot of time chasing this down.

Comment: `$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $content);` fixed it for me in PHP7 (so it is still an issue) - this is a really annoying problem, because I defined utf8 in the HTML document (with `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`) but that has no effect, it seems to need the <?xml part, which is totally unintuitive.

Comment: Still in 2017 this answer is relevant and worked for me too. I had my database, multibyte, html meta tag and DOM encoding all set to utf8 and still had bad encoding on importing node from one DOC to another. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php was the fix.

Comment: Using 'HTML-ENTITIES' is a horrible hack, but in october 2017, that is the only trick that is suggested on this page that works on RHEL7!

Comment: Prepending the xml encoding declaration to the string worked great. Opted for this solution vs the mb_convert_encoding. Thanks.

Comment: So what is HTML-ENTITIES ? Is this some kind of constant? What does this have to do with aformentioned ISO-8859-1 (ASCII) encoding? I know about the htmlentities function. BTW I still have the error.

Comment: It's one of the [supported encodings](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php) used by mbstring. The role of the conversion is to change the byte representation of the characters — e.g. "イ" will be represented with different bytes depending on the encoding — and the HTML-ENTITIES "encoding" is just a special example of that. [Here’s a gist](https://gist.github.com/cmbuckley/495da67b60e0453a7f18eb5060243566) that shows what's happening. ISO-8859-1 is the [default encoding for HTTP text documents according to the standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#History).

Comment: If the my data is already converted to strange charecters does it mean I have lost it

Comment: Depends what you mean - if you have stored some characters and they're reading as the wrong encoding, and you're seeing something like OP's example, then it's most likely recoverable, by looking at the hex encoding of the strange characters and using a conversion chart [such as this one for é](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/charset_support.htm). If the strange characters have been replaced with `?` or �, then you won't be able to recover the original.

Comment: This  saveHTTML, display correctly in browser, but not for actual string. @Greeso answer is better.

Comment: 10 years ago you gave the solution. I guess that is the problem of using libraries made for html4, any better recent alternatives?

Comment: Becareful! use `mb_convert_encoding()` will convert non-english text to entities. For example: `ส` will becomes `&#3626;`.

Comment: Yes, that’s the point, since those characters can’t be represented in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: If string doesn't contain `<meta>` with character set, I recommended use `mb_convert_encoding()` as in this **answer** but also use `$dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement)` to make the output as unicode text **NOT** HTML entities. Thank you @cmbuckley .

Comment: PHP8.2: `Deprecated: mb_convert_encoding(): Handling HTML entities via mbstring is deprecated; use htmlspecialchars, htmlentities, or mb_encode_numericentity/mb_decode_numericentity instead`

Comment: `<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>` no longer works since libxml2 2.12.0. `<meta charset="utf8">` still works.

Answer (score 94):

The problem is with `saveHTML()` and `saveXML()`, both of them do not work correctly in Unix. They do not save UTF-8 characters correctly when used in Unix, but they work in Windows.

The workaround is very simple:

If you try the default, you will get the error you described

```
$str = $dom->saveHTML(); // saves incorrectly
```

All you have to do is save as follows:

```
$str = $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement); // saves correctly
```

This line of code will get your UTF-8 characters to be saved correctly. Use the same workaround if you are using `saveXML()`.

---

**Update**

As suggested by "[Jack M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2167297/)" in the comments section below, and verified by "[Pamela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303123)" and "[Marco Aurélio Deleu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1014588)", the following variation might work in your case:

```
$str = utf8_decode($dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement));
```

---

**Update 2**

`utf8_decode` is now deprecated. An alternative is `mb_convert_encoding()`. You have to set it according to your needs.

---

### Note

1. English characters do not cause any problem when you use `saveHTML()` without parameters (because English characters are saved as single byte characters in UTF-8)
2. The problem happens when you have multi-byte characters (such as Chinese, Russian, Arabic, Hebrew, ...etc.)

I recommend reading this article: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/06/all-about-unicode-utf8-character-sets/. You will understand how UTF-8 works and why you have this problem. It will take you about 30 minutes, but it is time well spent.

Comment: I had to utf8_decode while using this solution. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by utf8_decode? I apologize but I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: This had to become utf8_decode($dom->saveHTML(dom->documentElement)) to preserve my special characters. Otherwise, they just became something else. Just mentioning it in case it helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks @MrJack. I also had to do the same to make it display without the strange characters `$str = utf8_decode($dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement));`

Comment: `utf8_decode($dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement));` did it perfectly for me.

Comment: This is not working for me. My Thai language still becomes **à¸ªà¸§à¸±à¸ªà¸à¸µà¸ à¸²à¸©à¸²à¹à¸à¸¢**.

Comment: @vee - Did you try what "Jack M" suggested in his comment above? Both "Pamela" and  "Marco Aurélio Deleu" followed his suggestion and it worked for them.

Comment: If that so, could you please update your answer to this one that they confirmed work. :)

Comment: not work correctly - better is `mb_convert_encoding()`

Comment: Great work, @Greeso, thanks! I had problems with `$dom -> saveXML()` where all extended Latin characters were being converted into HTML escapes and those HTML escapes were _then_ converted into XML escapes. Needless to say, strings like `Stani&amp;#x10D;n&amp;#xE9; n&amp;#xE1;mestie` aren't much use in XML (or any data) Thanks to your suggestion, I replaced `$dom -> saveXML();` with `$dom -> saveXML($dom -> documentElement);`. Everything is now fixed and I now see `Staničné námestie` correctly encoded in UTF-8. Thank you.

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine Well wow, It is going to be 10 years since I wrote this answer, glad it is still relevant.

Comment: PHP8.2: `Deprecated: Function utf8_decode() is deprecated`

Comment: @mickmackusa - Thank you. I updated the answer.

Comment: PHP8.2: `Deprecated: mb_convert_encoding(): Handling HTML entities via mbstring is deprecated; use htmlspecialchars, htmlentities, or mb_encode_numericentity/mb_decode_numericentity instead`  Please include a runnable 3v4l.org demo link to prove that your advice is current and works.

Comment: @mickmackusa - Unfortunately I do not have the setup for it right now to do a test (the answer is written a long while back). That said, I looked through PHP documentation. and also according to the error message you got, you can try the following: `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` or `mb_encode_numericentity` or even ` call_user_func_array('mb_convert_encoding', array(&$s,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8'))` (the last one from the comments of `mb_convert_encoding`). That said, the original answer before the update did not even use that encoding. It is updated based on comments.

Comment: Speaking only about HTML, why all the gyrations? Both HTML 4 and the parser supported UTF-8, just use the HTML 4 charset meta. Refer to @Alexander's answer. I tested on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 5.15.

Answer (score 21):

Make sure the real source file is saved as UTF-8 (You may even want to try the non-recommended BOM Chars with UTF-8 to make sure).

Also in case of HTML, make sure you have declared the correct encoding using `meta` tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

If it's a CMS (as you've tagged your question with Joomla) you may need to configure appropriate settings for the encoding.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I have no problems displaying the characters.  if I do "echo $profile;" it works fine.  it's when the DomDocument gets ahold of it that it starts failing.

Comment: Your meta prevents saveHTML from encoding everything above ASCII into entities. The solution I was looking for :)

Comment: As a side note, the newer `<meta charset="UTF-8">` tag doesn't work with DOMDocument.

Comment: @Taylan: no problem at all with `<meta charset="UTF-8">`: see https://3v4l.org/AATjh

Answer (score 19):

This took me a while to figure out but here's my answer.

Before using DomDocument I would use file_get_contents to retrieve URLs and then process them with string functions. Perhaps not the best way but quick. After being convinced Dom was just as quick I first tried the following:

```
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
if ($dom->loadHTMLFile($url) == false) { // read the url
    // error message
}
else {
    // process
}
```

This failed spectacularly in preserving UTF-8 encoding despite the proper meta tags, PHP settings, and all the rest of the remedies offered here and elsewhere. Here's what works:

```
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$str = file_get_contents($url);
if ($dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($str, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')) == false) {
}
```

etc. Now everything's right with the world.

Comment: Just wanted to add to my answer above that another way to address this is with the following, suggested elsewhere as well: if ($dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $str) == false). After posting my answer I found an occasion where my first suggestion failed but the second worked.

Comment: Works for me even without the params in `DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8')`. But in my case only partial html is loaded.

Comment: thanks a lot man, worked for me dealing with hebrew 

Comment: PHP8.2: `Deprecated: mb_convert_encoding(): Handling HTML entities via mbstring is deprecated; use htmlspecialchars, htmlentities, or mb_encode_numericentity/mb_decode_numericentity instead`

Answer (score 13):

### Use correct header for UTF-8

Don't get satisfied by "it works".

@cmbuckley in his accepted answer advised to set `<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>` to the document. However to use XML declaration in HTML document is a bit weird. HTML is not XML (unless it is XHTML) and it can confuse browsers and other software on the way to client (may be source of the failures reported by others).

I successfully used HTML5 declaration:

```
$profile = '<p>イリノイ州シカゴにて、アイルランド系の家庭に、9</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<!DOCTYPE html><meta charset="UTF-8">' . $profile);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

If you use other standard, use correct header, the DOMDocument follows the standards quite pedantically and seems to support HTML5, too (if not in your case, try to update the libxml extension).

Comment: There is no support for HTML5 in PHP, unfortunately, because libxml doesn't support it. You'd get the same results with `<!DOCTYPE alsfjaswrtoiufn>`, i.e. it would just output whatever you typed.

Comment: I'm running PHP 8.1.0 on Windows and adding only the tag <meta charset="UTF-8"> works fine for me. No need to use <html> neither <!DOCTYPE...>

Comment: The html5 charset meta, with mb input, would output every char html entity encoded. Confirm output with mb_strlen, or just view page source. Use the htm4 `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`for the html4 parser.

Answer (score 12):

You could prefix a line enforcing `utf-8` encoding, like this:

```
@$doc->loadHTML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n" . $profile);
```

And you can then continue with the code you already have, like:

```
$doc->saveXML()
```

Answer (score 6):

Use it for correct result

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">' . $profile);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
echo $profile;
```

This operation

```
mb_convert_encoding($profile, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

It is bad way, because special symbols like  &lt ; , &gt ; can be in $profile, and they will not convert twice after mb_convert_encoding.  It is the hole for XSS and incorrect HTML.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "they will not convert twice after mb_convert_encoding"?

Answer (score 5):

You must feed the DOMDocument a version of your HTML with a header that make sense.
Just like HTML5.

```
$profile ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.$_encoding.'"?>'. $html;
```

maybe  is a good idea to keep your html as valid as you can, so you don't get into issues when you'll start query... around :-) and stay away from `htmlentities`!!!!  That's an an necessary back and forth wasting resources. 
keep your code insane!!!!

Comment: this is more or less part of the accepted answere....

Answer (score 4):

Works finde for me:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(utf8_decode($html));
...
return  utf8_encode( $dom->saveHTML());
```

Comment: Be careful, utf8_decode may lose information (replaced with a `?`)

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that worked for me was the accepted answer of

```
$profile = '<p>イリノイ州シカゴにて、アイルランド系の家庭に、9</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $profile);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

HOWEVER

This brought about new issues, of having `<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>` in the output of the document.

The solution for me was then to do

```
foreach ($doc->childNodes as $xx) {
    if ($xx instanceof \DOMProcessingInstruction) {
        $xx->parentNode->removeChild($xx);
    }
}
```

Some solutions told me that to remove the `xml` header, that I had to perform

```
$dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

This didn't work for me as for a partial document (e.g. a doc with two `<p>` tags), only one of the `<p>` tags where being returned.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when you add a parameter to `DOMDocument::saveHTML()` function, you lose the encoding. In a few cases, you'll need to avoid the use of the parameter and use old string function to find what your are looking for.

I think the previous answer works for you, but since this workaround didn't work for me, I'm adding that answer to help people who may be in my case.