# Rogue element when parsing HTML with DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

Lets assume my $html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.createElement("video");document.createElement("audio");document.createElement("track");</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/gui/default/tinymcecontent.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/video-js/video.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/js/video-js/video-js.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">document.createElement("video");document.createElement("audio");document.createElement("track");</script>
    <script type"text/javascript" src="/includes/js/video-js/video.js"></script/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/js/video-js/video-js.css" />
</head>
<body style="font-family: arial;font-size: 12px;">
    <p> </p>
    <table width="100%">        
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to parse only elements, that are inside body tag with commands:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$full_dom = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
```

The result of

```
$dom->saveHTML($full_dom)
```

is

```
<body>\n<p>\/&gt;<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"\/includes\/js\/video-js\/video-js.css\"><\/p>\n<p>\u00a0<\/p>\n<table width=\"100%\"><\/table>\n<\/body>
```

Element

```
<p>\/&gt;<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"\/includes\/js\/video-js\/video-js.css\"><\/p>
```

comes from where?
Everything else is good, just this element gets transfered from head tag into elements of body tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the line :

```
<script type"text/javascript" src="/includes/js/video-js/video.js"></script/>
```

It is badly formed and should be :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/video-js/video.js"></script>
```

You have to check errors after `$dom->loadHTML()` to see what's happend :

```
foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
    print_r($error);
}
```

Comment: Gosh, I see.. What are my option for ignoring such errors that are in the section of html that I cannot control nor do I want to have anything with it? I try only to work on body tag, ignoring the rest..

Comment: @SubjectX I think you can't. But maybe you can try to replace your string before the `<body>` element before to parse it. Good luck.

Comment: @SubjectX - Note that a conforming HTML5 parser will handle your malformed HTML much better - i.e. the same way that browsers do. There are several suggestions for such php libraries in the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712503/how-to-make-html5-work-with-domdocument

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I do work on some legacy code, so implementing additional libraries is not that optimal for now..