# PHP Warning DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag section invalid in Entity on line 10

Tags: php, xml, html, apache, domdocument

Here is line 10:

```
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>'.$request->getData());
```

And here is the whole code snippet from my backend:

```
class ParseImageLinks{
public function __construct(){
}

public function Run(\DataLayer\Gallery\Requests\ParseImageLinks $request){
    $doc = new \DOMDocument('1.0');
    $doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>'.$request->getData());

    $images = $doc->getElementsByTagName ( "img");

    foreach ($images as $key => $value){
        $src = $value->getAttribute("src");
        $local = false;

        if ($src[0] == 'h') {
            $src = explode("http://", $src)[1];
        }else{
            if ($src[0] == '/') {
                $src = substr($src,1);
                $local = true;
            }
        }

        $parse = explode('/', $src);
        if (count($parse) > 2 && ($local || $parse[0] == $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] || $parse[0] == 'localhost:8080')) {
            $image = $parse[count($parse)-1];
            $size = $parse[count($parse)-2];

            $value->setAttribute("src", '/?image='.$image."&size=".$size);
        }
    }

    return $doc->saveHTML();
}
}
```

I spent several hours searching the web. Here is what I have tried so far:

- `@$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>'.$request->getData());`
- `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
  $doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>'.$request->getData());`
- I created a test.php file with this

  ```
  <?php
  $doc = new \DOMDocument('1.0');
  $doc->loadHTML('<ul><li>text</li>'.
  '<li>&frac12; of this is <strong>strong</strong</li></ul>');
  foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('li') as $node)
  {
      echo htmlentities(iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $node->nodeValue)), "\n";
  }
  ?>
  ```

  which by the following command `php -f test.php > res.html` occured in file res.html with `text` inside it.
- I also checked if `xml` module is loaded and it is.

So, if I understand correct DOMDocument() thing workes in general, but not in the file in question. Why?

**UPD**. I'm not sure, but this seems like a reason for images not to be loaded properly.

Comment: Why are you adding an `<?xml .. ?>` tag when you are using `loadHTML`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I inherited this code and just trying to go through it all, fixing bugs on the way...And I'm also a newbie at php. Could you explain why do you think this tag is an excess? On different answers on similar problem I saw this usage - nobody mentioned it was wrong by any means...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `DOMDocument` is still not able to parse an html5 document. You need to deal with a silent error mechanism workaround as shown in these questions:

- [How to make HTML5 work with DOMDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712503/how-to-make-html5-work-with-domdocument)
- [PHP DOMDocument errors/warnings on html5-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090667/php-domdocument-errors-warnings-on-html5-tags)