# PHP DOMDocument fails if 'table' is inside 'a'

Tags: php, dom

I am parsing a website's HTML and there is a 'table' inside an 'a':

```
<?php 

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML("<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <a>
      <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>");

if ($dom->getElementsByTagName("table")->item(0)->parentNode->nodeName == "body")
  echo "Why is table a child of 'body'? It should be a child of 'a'.";
```

I also get this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : a in Entity, line: ...
```

I am using PHP 7.4.

I know 'table's are not officially allowed inside 'a's. BUT:

1. The warning is a completely different message.
2. Making the 'table' a child of 'body' because I've put it inside an 'a' does not make sense.

What can I do? I want that at least the table is not a child of body. Because like this I cannot parse sites properly.

Edit: Please read the comments under this question. Tables are allowed inside 'a's in this case in HTML5. So this behavior is even more strange.

Comment: In fact, DOMDocument "fixes" your HTML: `echo $dom->saveHTML();` will show you that the `<table>` has been moved outside the `<a>`. I tried the "hacks" I know about DOMDocument but nothing worked so far.

Comment: The warning is completely wrong. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: *I know 'table's are not officially allowed inside 'a's.* — Yes they are, they weren't in HTML 4, but that changed years ago.

Comment: @Quentin Do you have a link to the part of the HTML5 specification saying that tables are allowed inside 'a'?

Comment: @zomega - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: @Quentin Well that is only a link to the 'a' element. Where exactly does it say tables are allowed inside them?

Comment: In the Content model section.

Comment: @Quentin You have to be a little more precise. It only says "transparent" which kind of inherits from the parent.

Comment: @Quentin You said in HTML5 tables are allowed inside 'a's in general. At least that is what your comment suggested. But that cannot be as the spec says "transparent".

Comment: @zomega — You read too much into my comment. They are allowed in many cases, including the one in the question in particular.

Answer (score 0):

When loading HTML content, **DOMDocument** *"fixes"* your document. You can see by printing the parsed HTML that the `<table>` has been moved outside the `<a>`:

```php
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output (not formatted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body>
    <a>
        </a><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

You can try loading your document as XML instead:

```php
$dom->loadXml('your HTML string');
```

Calling `$dom->saveXml()` shows the document structure has not changed.
You get the correct parent node when fetching the `<table>`:

```php
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName("table")->item(0)->parentNode->nodeName;
// Output: a
```

---

Wild guess about the warning you got (I don't know how it works internally, I can't be sure):

The parser sees the opening `<a>` and then the opening `<table>`:

```
...<body><a><table>
```

As it considers having a `<table>` inside a `<a>` is "wrong", it closes the `<a>` before the opening `<table>`:

```
...<body><a></a><table>
```

Later in the document, it finds your original closing `</a>`, alone, which throws the error of *"Unexpected end tag"*

```
...<body><a></a><table>...</table></a>
```

Comment: I would mark your answer as accepted. But please read the comments under my question. Tables are allowed inside 'a's.

Comment: @zomega okay then I guess your question could be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712503/how-to-make-html5-work-with-domdocument): DOMDocument doesn't follow HTML5 specs. I'm afraid I can't improve my answer that much, that's the only workaround I found.