# domdocument character set issue

Tags: php, domdocument

This the video from witch i want to get the **og:title**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=A683kmvRH_8

Php code

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

        $html = file_get_contents_curl($pageurl);

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($html);
        $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

        $titleBackUp = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

        for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++){
            $meta = $metas->item($i);
            if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'title')
                $title = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        }
```

The title is **Мастило - В ръцете ти е най-добре [HQ]** and i'm getting

**ÐÐ°ÑÑÐ¸Ð»Ð¾ - Ð ÑÑÑÐµÑÐµ ÑÐ¸ Ðµ Ð½Ð°Ð¹-Ð´Ð¾Ð±ÑÐµ [HQ]**

I try also with

```
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8" );
```

but it dosent work.

I try with **html_entity_decode** but is not working

Comment: Instead of `@$doc->loadHTML()` you can use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` and `libxml_clear_errors()`

Comment: What is encoding of a page you are printing results?

Comment: The title is inserted into the database and has utf-8 ecnoding . The page in witch i print the result have   <meta charset="UTF-8">
 html5

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP DOMDocument loadHTML not encoding UTF-8 correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if the document itself doesn't contain a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` tag.

You can try either of the following:

1. Let `DomDocument` load the HTML directly from the server (i.e. use `->loadHTMLFile()`)
2. Prefix the document with aforementioned meta tag before running it through `->loadHTML()`.

For example, you could do this:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />' . $html);
libxml_clear_errors();
```

It's a hack to let libxml know it's supposed to read utf-8 data ... it's not possible to pass that encoding via `->loadHTML()`.

Comment: @HmmlollolGadnqri ... about? which part do you need help with? I've updated the answer, hope that helps.

Comment: You suggest to change  @$doc->loadHTML($html); to  @$doc->loadHTMLFile($html); and how to do the second step. Also how to change the code with libxml_use_internal_errors(true) and libxml_clear_errors()

Comment: @HmmlollolGadnqri sorry! I meant either of those two options.

Comment: This is also useful if you load HTML snippets which do not have any meta data.