# DOMDocument breaks encoding?

Tags: php, encoding, domdocument

I run the following code:

```
$page = '<p>Ä</p>';
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($page);
echo 'source:'.$page;
echo 'dom: '.$DOM->getElementsByTagName('p')->item (0)->textContent;
```

and it outputs the following:

> source: Ä
>
> dom: Ã

so, I don't understand why when the text comes through DOMDocument its encoding becomes broken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DOMDocument` appears to be treating the input as UTF-8. In this conversion, `Ä` becomes `Ã„`. Here's the catch: That second character does not exist in ISO-8859-1, but does exist in Windows-1252. This is why you are seeing no second character in your output.

You can fix this by calling `utf8_decode` on the output of `textContent`, or using UTF-8 as your page's character encoding.

Comment: Just struggled with this issue, too,and unfortunately came across one case where utf8_decode could not help. iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", $data) cames to rescue! (more info: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php#104907 )

Answer (score 8):

Here's a workaround that adds the proper encoding via meta header:

```
$DOM->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />' . $page);
```

*I'm not sure if that's the actual character set you're trying to use, but adjust where necessary*

See also: [domdocument character set issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852898/domdocument-character-set-issue/10853027#10853027)

Comment: Domdocument's parsing of document encoding seems to be broken. Further, this workaround is the only way I could get it not to ruin the text content of an utf-8 page which it fails to recognise as utf-8.