# wrong characters encoding DOMDocument php

Tags: php, character-encoding, domdocument

i have some html content that all of its texts are Persian !
i want to give this content to DOMDocument by method DOMDocument::loadHTML($html) to do some stuff and then give it back by DOMDocument::saveHTML() ... but there is a problem in showing characters :-(
for example "سلام" changed to "Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…", even I changed my script file encoding to UTF-8 but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$html = "<html><meta charset='utf-8' /> سلام</html>";

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->loadHTML($html);
print $html; // output : سلام
print $doc->saveHTML(); // output : Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…
print $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement); // output : Ø³ÙØ§Ù
?>
```

UPDATE: according to friends instruction, i used $doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
 and it worked !

Comment: Is the HTML content even UTF8?

Comment: when you use your `create...` function, where do you get your `$HTML` from? you need to make sure that you use utf8 on every component, especially if you use a database, you need to have the data in the tables in utf8 AND set the database api to use utf8 to send the data

Comment: Thanks, now i updated my question and i added a code ... this code does'nt have anything !!

Comment: Have you tried to print `$html` before doing anything with it?

Comment: yes when i print $html it shows سلام

Comment: This might help:

[PHP DomDocument saveHTML not encoding Japanese correctly][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-savehtml-not-encoding-japanese-correctly

Comment: Thank you so much ! Worked !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$html = '<html>سلام</html>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
```

Converting the character encoding of string `$html`, to UTF-8 and then load it to the DOM, using 2  `libxml` predefined constants (`LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` & `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD`).

The first one sets `HTML_PARSE_NOIMPLIED flag`, which turns off the automatic adding of implied html/body... elements (which is only avilable as of PHP 5.4.0).

The second one sets `HTML_PARSE_NODEFDTD` flag, which prevents a default doctype being added when one is not found. using these constants help you manage your parsing in a more flexible manner.

```
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

Then you define the DOM encoding, itself (the previouse definition was for input):

```
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8';
```

Remove leading and trailing `<html>` & `<body>` tags, in case you are not using libxml 2.7.7 (as of PHP >= 5.4.0):

```
$doc->normalizeDocument(); //Remove leading and trailing <html> & <body> tags
print $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

Tell the XML parser that the data being read is UTF-8 encoded:

```
<?php

// original input (unknown encoding)
$html = '<html>سلام</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();

// specify the input encoding
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8"?>' . $html);

// specify the output encoding
$doc->encoding = 'utf-8';

// output: <html><body><p>سلام</p></body></html>
print $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);
```