# PHP CURL returned text corrupted with utf-8 greek

Tags: php, curl, utf-8

I have a problem regarding PHP, CURL and UT-8 Greek characters.

I try to retrieve some text from a website (a blog specifically), but when i read the retrieved text it is corrupted. It shows up something like **Î ÏÎºÎ¿ÏÏÏ ÏÎ¿Ï ÏÏÏÏÎ¿Î½**. The english characters on the other hand show up nice.

The website's charset is 'UTF-8' and so is the charset in my script.

I use the following settings for CURL.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$useragent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20120716 Firefox/15.0a2';
$header = array('Accept-Charset: UTF-8');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
```

I use an Xpath Query `$res=$xp->query("...")` to find the place of the text.

Then i take the text like this:

```
foreach($res as $text_result)
    $texter=trim($text_result->nodeValue);
```

I checked the returned text charset with `mb_detect_encoding` and its properly 'UTF-8'.

The script runs correctly with most of the websites, but it fails with two of them.
I can't figure out what the problem may be.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you all in advance.

UPDATE

I have fixed the error by adding this:

```
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);
```

but now, when i insert the text into the database, they remain corrupted. The same in my pc (easyphp) works fine.

I own a free host at 000webhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had to convert the html entities encoding, by:

```
@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($data, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

Solution was given here: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-savehtml-not-encoding-japanese-correctly/)