# Character Encoding/decoding becomes a mess

Tags: php, ajax, character-encoding

In a webapp I place a `<div id="xxx" contentEditable=true >` for editing purpose. The `encodeURIComponent(xxx.innerHTML)` will be send via Ajax `POST` type to a server, where a PHP script creates a simple txt file from it which in turn can be downloaded from the user to store it locally or print it on screen. It works perfect so far, but … Yes, but, character encoding is a mess. All special characters like the german `Ä` are interpretated wrong. In this case as `ÃÂ¤`
I google for some days and I study PHP methods like `iconv()` and I know how to set up a browsers character encoding and also set a text editor for a correct correspondending decoding. But nothing helps, its still a messs, or becoming even weired.

So my question is : Where in this encoding/decoding roundtrip from the browser to a server and back to the browser I have to do what, to ensure that an `Ä` will still be an `Ä` ?

Answer (score 2):

I answer my question, because it turns out to be another problem as stated above. The `contenteditable` is actually part of a section of html code. On the serverside with PHP I need to filter out the `contenteditable` text which I do via a DOMDocument like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($_POST["data"]);
```

then I access the elements and their textual content as usual.
Finally I save the text with

```
file_put_contents($txtFile,  $plainText, LOCK_EX);
```

The saved text then was a mess as written above. Now it turns out that you need to tell the DOMDocument the character set wich `loadHTML()` has to interpretate. In this case UTF-8.
First I did it as recommended in PHP this way :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
```

But that doesn't help (I wonder). Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly) answer in SO. And the final solution is this :

```
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $_POST["data"]);
```

Though it works it is a trick. Finally the question is left over, how to do it the right way ? If somebedoy has the definite answer, he is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the content is encoded consistently throughout its roundtrip from user input to server-side storage and back to the browser again.

I would recommend using UTF-8. Check that your HTML document (which includes the `contenteditable` zone) is UTF-8 encoded, and that the XMLHttpRequest/Ajax request does not specify a different encoding when it sends the content to the server.

Check that your server-side application encodes the text file as UTF-8 also. And check that the HTTP response headers declare the file's encoding as UTF-8 when the file is requested and downloaded in the browser.

Somewhere along this path, the encoding differs, and that is what is causing the error. `iconv` converts between different encodings, which should not be necessary if everything is consistent.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your hints. The HTML document which inherits the `conteneditable` is declared as `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Can this be overwritten ?  XMLHttpRequest/Ajax request has no specific encoding, except 'encodeURIComponent'. So UTF-8 should walk through. serverside I have no special encoding/decoding setup. How to do that ? Where to declare  HTTP response headers for downlaoding ?

Comment: The `Content-Type` HTTP header in the response will override any character encoding declared in the HTML document itself, e.g. using the `<meta charset>` tag. Check in your console for a `Content-Type` header value of "text/html; charset=utf-8" for the web page and "text/plain; charset=utf-8" for the file download. If these are wrong, correct them in your server-side application with PHP's `header()` function: http://php.net/header :)