# Symfony dom-crawler string in script tag convert to UTF8

Tags: php, symfony, utf-8, domcrawler

I have this HTML content:

```
<div>测试</div>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    function drawCharts(){
        console.log('测试');
    }
</script>
```

When I use the Symfony's dom-crawler, the text is being HTML encoded. How can I prevent this? `$crawler->html()` results:

```
<div>测试</div>
<script>
    function drawCharts(){
        console.log('&#27979;&#35797;');
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's see how symfony/dom-crawler works. Here's an example to start with:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$html = <<<HTML
<div>测试</div>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    function drawCharts(){
        console.log('测试');
    }
</script>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

print $crawler->html();
```

It outputs:

```
<div>æµè¯</div>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    function drawCharts(){
        console.log('&aelig;&micro;&#139;&egrave;&macr;&#149;');
    }
</script>
```

When you pass the content through the [constructor](https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler/blob/adb9f190b13884d6a70ec094a487363675575c1a/Crawler.php#L62), the `Crawler` class [does its best](https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler/blob/adb9f190b13884d6a70ec094a487363675575c1a/Crawler.php#L125) to figure out the encoding. If it fails to figure anything out, it [falls back to `ISO-8859-1`](https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler/blob/adb9f190b13884d6a70ec094a487363675575c1a/Crawler.php#L141); which is the default charset defined by the HTTP 1.1 specification.

If your HTML content contains a [charset meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type), the Crawler class will read the charset from it, set it and [convert from it](https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler/blob/adb9f190b13884d6a70ec094a487363675575c1a/Crawler.php#L176) properly. Here's the same above example with a charset meta tag prepended to the HTML content:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$html = <<<HTML
<meta charset="utf-8">
<div>测试</div>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    function drawCharts(){
        console.log('测试');
    }
</script>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

print $crawler->html();
```

Now it prints:

```
<div>测试</div>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    function drawCharts(){
        console.log('&#27979;&#35797;');
    }
</script>
```

If you don't want to add the charset meta tag, there's another way; [`addHTMLContent()`](https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler/blob/adb9f190b13884d6a70ec094a487363675575c1a/Crawler.php#L164) method accepts a charset as its second argument and it defaults to `UTF-8`. Instead of passing the HTML content through the constructor, first instantiate the class and then add the content using this method:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$html = <<<HTML
<div>测试</div>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    function drawCharts(){
        console.log('测试');
    }
</script>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler;

// You can safely drop the 2nd argument
$crawler->addHTMLContent($html, 'UTF-8');     

print $crawler->html();
```

Now, without a charset meta tag, it prints:

```
<div>测试</div>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    function drawCharts(){
        console.log('&#27979;&#35797;');
    }
</script>
```

OK, you may already knew all of this. So, what's with the `&#27979;&#35797;`? Why the `div` content are showing as is, but the same content in the `script` tag is getting html-encoded?

Symfony's `Crawler` class, [as it explains itself](https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler/blob/adb9f190b13884d6a70ec094a487363675575c1a/Crawler.php#L175), converts the content to HTML entities due to a bug in [`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php):

> When using `loadHTML()` to process UTF-8 pages, you may meet the problem that the output of DOM functions are not like the input. For example, if you want to get "Cạnh tranh", you will receive "Cáº¡nh tranh". I suggest we use `mb_convert_encoding` before loading UTF-8 page.
>   – https://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#74777

Some suggest to add a HTML4 `Content-Type` meta tag into the head element. Some other suggest to prepend a `<?xml encoding="UTF-8">` to the HTML content before passing it to `loadHTML()`. As your HTML structure is not complete (lacks `head`, `body`, etc.), I recommend you simply pass the output to `html_entity_decode()`:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$html = <<<HTML
<div>测试</div>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    function drawCharts(){
        console.log('测试');
    }
</script>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addHTMLContent($html, 'UTF-8');

print html_entity_decode($crawler->html());
```

Outputs:

```
<div>测试</div>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    function drawCharts(){
        console.log('测试');
    }
</script>
```

Which is what you want.

You might also want to read:
[PHP DOMDocument loadHTML not encoding UTF-8 correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly)