# Why PHP DOMDocument loadHTML doesn't work for Persian characters?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, unicode, utf-8

#### [Here is my code](https://3v4l.org/DqZKu):

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<div>
    <p>سلام</p>                                         // focus on this line
    <p class="myclass">Remove this one</p>
    <p>But keep this</p>
    <div style="color: red">and this</div>
    <div style="color: red">and <p>also</p> this</div>
    <div style="color: red">and this <div style="color: red">too</div></div>
</div>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($data, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query("//*[@*]") as $node) {
    $parent = $node->parentNode;
    while ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        $parent->insertBefore($node->lastChild, $node->nextSibling);
    }
    $parent->removeChild($node);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

As I've mentioned in the title of my question, the content of my website is Persian *(not English)*. But code about doesn't work for Persian characters.

**Current output:**

```
.
.
    <p>&#1587;&#1604;&#1575;&#1605;</p>
.
.
```

**Expected output:**

```
.
.
    <p>سلام</p>
.
.
```

What's wrong with it and how can I fix it?

**Note:** Also as you see I've used `mb_convert_encoding($data, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')` to make it correct *(based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly#8218649))* but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Persian characters are being encoded as numeric character references. They'll appear appropriately in a browser or you can see the original by decoding them with `html_entity_decode()`, e.g.:

```
echo html_entity_decode("&#1587;&#1604;&#1575;&#1605;");
```

outputs:

```
سلام
```

---

If you prefer the original characters in the output rather than numeric character references, you can change:

```
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

to:

```
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
```

This alters the serialization a bit and the result is:

```
<div>
    <p>سلام</p>
    Remove this one
    <p>But keep this</p>
    and this
    and <p>also</p> this
    and this too
</div>
```

[Example.](https://3v4l.org/A3Ck1)

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot.