# How to manipulate multilingual data in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a project that will receive data in any possible language. Right now I'm trying to parse wiki page and get the [list of languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) and put it into DB. Already on the parsing step I found out that most of the native names are shown with " "(empty squares and stuff) and other strange symbols. The defined charset is UTF-8.

I am not sure how this works and have no idea where to dig further. I couldn't find any information about multi language contents on websites. Should I get like a code of all the symbols to use them? How to make this work?

I need to:

- Language name in English, native and short one to be added to db;
- Display that data in any country correctly(the encode thing);
- People will be able to add data on the selected language that will also be saved in the database with a link to the language name from the previously described table.

Right now I have some problems with encoding so some text is shown incorrectly as on the image below. What I already have is here(here is only 1 line of a table from wiki):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$html = '<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter" id="Table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#ACE1AF;width:#ACE1AF;"></td>
<td><a href="/wiki/Northwest_Caucasian_languages" title="Northwest Caucasian languages">Northwest Caucasian</a></td>
<td><a href="/wiki/Abkhazian_language" class="mw-redirect" title="Abkhazian language">Abkhazian</a></td>
<td lang="ab" xml:lang="ab">аҧсуа бызшәа, аҧсшәа</td>
<td><span class="plainlinks"><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/langcodes_name.php?iso_639_1=ab">ab</a></span></td>
<td>abk</td>
<td>abk</td>
<td>abk</td>
<td>also known as Abkhaz</td>
</tr>
</tbody><tfoot></tfoot></table>';

$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue.' ';
    echo $cols->item(3)->nodeValue.' ';
    echo $cols->item(4)->nodeValue.'<br>';
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

The output looks like this: [image]

But, if I try to output the `$html` it shows everything correctly. I use Google Chrome, last version. I need some clues and tips about how this works and how I can make my thing work properly.

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that DOMDocument component can not work correctly with chars not from latin 1 charset.

Change line `$dom->loadHTML($html);` to

```
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

This should help.

[More info in the related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218649/2641693)

Answer (score 1):

Change the Database, Tables And Columns `Collation` to `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`, Also keep in mind the the Max `UNIQUE` `VARCHAR` Length is `191`.

As i know `PHPMyAdmin` sets the collation to `latin1_swedish_ci` as default,

But this collation isn't recommend for multiple languages websites,

`UTF8` is made for this reason,

Also at the end of the name `ci` here means `Case Insensitive`

Comment: Thx for the reply. But I have this problem on PHP side. When I "echo" content to html there are squares. Is there any way to make it show correctly on any computer? Save data to database is my next step of suffering :)

Comment: @Telion If possible, Please put the code that contains the problem And what browser do you use to preview the code, That if the collation is already set to `UTF8`.

Comment: Not a problem. Give me some time.

Comment: Ok, there it is.

Comment: (actually, my PHPmyadmin makes default collation `utf8_general_ci` so everything worked by default)