# not cleared text with strip_tags and str_replace after implode

Tags: php, str-replace, strip-tags

This code  must be a text strign which have text from   which separeted  ';'.

```
$text='<p class="users_attr" style=""></p>
    <h3 class="show_user_h3" style=""><a href="/ru/tutors/violin/" class="link_users_attr">Игра на скрипке, виолончели</a></h3>
    , 
    <h3 class="show_user_h3" style=""><a href="/ru/tutors/hrafika-1/" class="link_users_attr">Искусствоведение</a></h3>
    , 
    <h3 class="show_user_h3" style=""><a href="/ru/tutors/uroki-vokala/" class="link_users_attr">Уроки вокала</a></h3>
    , 
    <h3 class="show_user_h3" style=""><a href="/ru/tutors/hra-na-fortepano/" class="link_users_attr">Игра на фортепиано</a></h3>
    , 
    <h3 class="show_user_h3" style=""><a href="/ru/tutors/sopilka/" class="link_users_attr">Игра на флейте</a></h3>
    , 
    <h3 class="show_user_h3" style=""><a href="/ru/tutors/muzika/" class="link_users_attr">Музыка</a></h3>
    , 
    <h3 class="show_user_h3" style=""><a href="/ru/tutors/psykholohiia/" class="link_users_attr">Психология</a></h3>
    <p style=""></p>';
```

I do it with this functions:

```
$data['cats'] = explode('</h3>', $text);
$data['cats'] = implode("; ", $data['cats']);   
$data['cats'] = strip_tags($data['cats'], '<h3><a><p>');
$data['cats'] = str_replace(" , ", "", $data['cats']);
```

After functions $text is it:

```
<p class="users_attr"></p>
<h3 class="show_user_h3">
<a href="/ru/tutors/violin/" class="link_users_attr">Игра на скрипке, виолончели</a>; , 
<h3 class="show_user_h3">
<a href="/ru/tutors/hrafika-1/" class="link_users_attr">Искусствоведение</a>; , 
<h3 class="show_user_h3">
<a href="/ru/tutors/uroki-vokala/" class="link_users_attr">Уроки вокала</a>; , 
<h3 class="show_user_h3">
<a href="/ru/tutors/hra-na-fortepano/" class="link_users_attr">Игра на фортепиано</a>; , 
<h3 class="show_user_h3">
<a href="/ru/tutors/sopilka/" class="link_users_attr">Игра на флейте</a>; , 
<h3 class="show_user_h3">
<a href="/ru/tutors/muzika/" class="link_users_attr">Музыка</a>; , 
<h3 class="show_user_h3">
<a href="/ru/tutors/psykholohiia/" class="link_users_attr">Психология</a>;
```

Why strip_tags did'nt strip html tags and why str_replace did'nt delete this parts of text ' , ' ?

Comment: `strip_tags` – *"You can use the optional second parameter to specify tags which __should not be stripped__."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've stripped all of the tags away, you will only need to replace commas (which are lead and trailed by one-or-more whitespace characters) with a semi-colon then a space.  I'll add `trim()` to mop up any lingering whitespace characters at the start or end of the finished string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Nr4VP))

```
echo trim(preg_replace('~\s+,\s+~', '; ', strip_tags($text)));
```

Output:

```
Игра на скрипке, виолончели; Искусствоведение; Уроки вокала; Игра на фортепиано; Игра на флейте; Музыка; Психология
```

---

Perhaps a more stable alternative would be to parse the html and extract the nodeValues from the `<a>` tags.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GJ5gc))

```
$dom=new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $text);  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218649/2943403
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$data['cats'] = [];
foreach ($xpath->query("//a") as $node) {
    $data['cats'][] = $node->nodeValue;
}
echo implode('; ', $data['cats']);
// same result
```

Comment: Thank you. Variant with DOMDocument is the best.