# Laravel 5.2 Maatwebsite Excel::load not parsing Japanese characters

Tags: laravel, csv, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using Maatwebsite excel v ~2.1.0 for my Laravel 5.2 project. My problem is that the japanese characters are not rendered as seen the photo below. As you can see, I have 23 heading rows and the displayed data only are only English characters. Columns that uses Japanese characters are null.

[image: data]

This is my data in my CSV file.

[image]

This is my approach in loading the CSV file:

```
Excel::load(request()->file('file'), function($reader) {
    $results = $reader->all();
    dd($results);
});
```

What should I change to make the Japanese characters readable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP DOMDocument loadHTML not encoding UTF-8 correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly)

Comment: @rkg Unfortunately, that is HTML element encoding, not CSV. I have answered my question anyway, please see below.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after exploring more, I found out the answer. In excel.php file, I changed `'to_ascii' => true,` to `'to_ascii' => false` and my problem is fixed. Hope this helps someone in the near future.