# Problem with encoding after using DOMXpath

Tags: php, utf-8, domxpath

I web scrape (using curl) a page and try to retrive LD-Json content.

So first I get the content of the page:

```
  $handle = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

  $page = curl_exec($handle);
  curl_close($handle);
```

and it works ok.

I check the $data content in a hex editor and see that the page is encoded correctly as UTF-8.
For example characters "ół" are encoded as "**C3 B3 C5 82**" which is OK.

The problem starts when I query for ld-json scripts:

```
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  @$dom->loadHTML($page);
  $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
  $jsonScripts = $xpath->query( '//script[@type="application/ld+json"]' );
```

and then

```
      foreach ($jsonScripts as $jScript)
      {
          $json = $jScript->nodeValue;
          $data = json_decode($cleared, true);
```

suddenly the same characters are now encoded as "**C3 83 C2 B3 C3 85 C2 82**"

What just happend?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218649/231316) which says that DOMDocument works in ISO-8859-1 be default and you need to kick it into UTF-8 mode. It is possible that the site you are loading this from has that in the HTTP header and not the HTML, too.

Comment: @ChrisHaas - thank you 100 times. Indeed, there was a problem with the document. The character set was defined as <meta charset=UTF-8> not <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: I’m glad that worked! Instead of editing the question with your answer, please roll that back and instead post it as an answer and accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*SOLVED*

The problem was in the scraped page.
The character set was defined as

```
<meta charset=UTF-8>
```

not

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

The workaround was to change the code to:

```
  @$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>'.$page);
```

Thank you @ChrisHaas!