# innerHTML of PHP DOMDocument and HTML entities

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, html-entities

I save `innerHTML` of an element by

```
function innerHTML(DOMNode $el){
    $html='';
        foreach($el->childNodes as $node){
            $temp=new DOMDocument();
            $temp->appendChild($temp->importNode($node,true));
            $html.=trim($t->saveHTML());
         }
    return (string)$html;
}
```

The problem is that it converts characters to HTML entities (`&ndash;`, `&alpha;`, etc).

The solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly) is to set the encoding when loading into the document as

```
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($profile, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

but I do not load an HTML. The DOMDocument is just a temporary document for saving the imported nodes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP DOMDocument loadHTML not encoding UTF-8 correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly)

Comment: @Michel this is one of the materials I read. How can I apply `$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $profile);`? I don't have a document to load. Instead, I create a temporary document and importNode. How do you apply encoding when creating DOMDocument or importNode. This is indeed my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP function `html_entity_decode($html)` to convert HTML entities.

Comment: it's surely a solution. However, I was familiar with the standard function for decoding HTML entities. I look for a standard method to save the original character encoding in `DOMDocument`.