# How does php utf8_decode deal with utf8mb4?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, utf8mb4

I am working on localhost windows10 apache 2.4: `Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/8.0.11`and `Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.0.11` which uses the server `Server version: 10.4.21-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution`. It is by default set to _utf8mb4: `Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)`.

I made a php script that gets content(including html tags) from a Wikipedia page using `loadHTMLFile`. I then further use `xpath->query` to filter the dom and then the data is saved in mysql table as a string after being escaped by `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Later on, I query the database and save the content in a variable which is passed to `loadHTML`, then I remove a few dom elements and then pass the modified content to `saveHTML` and echo it to my webpage.

What happens is some characters are being displayed like:

`&nbsp; --> Â` 
`-      --> â€“`
`€    -->   â‚¬`
`ευρώ --> ÎµÏ…ÏÏŽÂ`

All the characters are displayed correctly, when I use `echo utf8_decode($output)`. Note: that instead of using `utf8_decode`, any of the following has no effect:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">  // in my html file  
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); // before the echo statement      
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8"); // before mysql insert into and Select from statements 
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8"); // before mysql insert into and Select from
```

statements

Also both `mb_detect_encoding($output)` and `mb_detect_encoding(utf8_decode($output))` returns `UTF-8` **not** `utf8mb4`. In my chrome browser's network/headers tab, I always get *Content-type* as `text/html; charset=UTF-8` , regardless of whatever changes I make in my server side php/mysql settings.

My guess is that, the data in the Wikipedia page is in normal `UTF-8` form, which is automatically **converted** by php into `utf8mb4` when it's downloaded by `loadHTMLFile`. Now this data is saved in mysql tables in `utf8mb4` format. This data when retrieved later on stays in `utf8mb4` format and is seen to the browser in `utf8mb4` format. When I use `utf8_decode` it must convert it to normal `utf-8` format.

The problem with my guess is that the php docs about [utf8_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode) page, mention nothing of `utf8mb4`, rather it says, multi-byte `UTF-8 ISO-8859-1` encoding is converted into single byte `UTF-8 ISO-8859-1`. Secondly the docs say, *ISO-8859-1 charset does not contain the EURO sign*. But my webpage successfully shows euro sign after `utf8_decode` and a browser is capable of parsing multibyte utf-8 characters as well, so if that was the only thing that `utf8_decode` does, then it should not make any difference with my code.

**Edit:**

I found the culprit. The following echos correct characters:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("Select ...");
...
$result = $stmt->execute();
...
$row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc()

echo $row['content']; // gives €ερυώ
```

Now, `$row['content']` is the data directly from my database without any utf_decode. But I happen to use php `domdocument` afterwards and the following happens:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // important
$content = new DOMDocument();
$content->loadHTML($row['content']);
echo $row['content'], $content->saveHTML($content); die();
// The output is:  €ερυώ
//â¬ÎµÏÏÏ
```

The output from the above code in my *view source* is:

```
€ερυώ<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>â¬ÎµÏÏÏ</p></body></html>
```

So please explain what the heck does `loadHTML` and `saveHTML` is doing here?

---

P.S: My whole code available on github repo: https://github.com/AnupamKhosla/crimeWiki and the speciic scripts about wikipedea pages encoding at https://github.com/AnupamKhosla/crimeWiki/blob/main/include/wikipedea_code.php  https://github.com/AnupamKhosla/crimeWiki/blob/main/include/post_code.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (`SELECT @@version;`)

Comment: "ISO-8859-1" is probably closest to MySQL's "latin1".

Comment: Now, that you posted the edit in your question, it is clear that the problem is not with mysqli. The problem is that you didn't specify the correct encoding for your DOMDocument. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47396055/1839439

Comment: @Dharman Interestingly, opposite to the link you gave, When I load a wikipedea url with `$tmp = new DOMDocument(); $tmp->loadHTMLFile($url)` all the characters are encoded in utf-8 and the data saved in my database is stillin utf-8 format. It is when I query that data and create html dom back from it with `$content = new DOMDocument();
   $content->loadHTML($row['content']); `, I get encoding problems.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that `utf8_decode()` helps you is incidental. This function should not be used most of the time. If using it helps you, then it can only mean that somehow you have managed to mangle your data.

`utf8mb4` is MySQL's charset that represents the full UTF-8 encoding. Therefore, if you are using UTF-8 everywhere in your code, you should never need to use `utf8_decode()` as it will only damage the data. ISO-8859-1 supports very few characters. It's not what you want.

What seems to have happened here is that you forgot to set `$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4')` when you opened the connection. Many MySQL servers default to `Latin1` when you don't specify the charset, which means that even though your schema might be using `utf8mb4` consistently, the connection to the database doesn't and converts the data into garbled up text.

The solution is simple, always set the right connection charset right after opening a new mysqli connection. `$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4')` will solve your problem and you don't need to use the ridiculous `utf8_decode()` function that accidentally solved your problem.

Comment: Additionally, the € symbol was surviving the process because MySQL also lies when it claims Latin-1. In fact it's using Windows-1252. ([Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-we-sets.html)).

Comment: Unfortunately `$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4')` did not change anything, as I mentioned in the question. My phpmyadmin page mentions `Server connection collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and `Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)`. Also, the php ini file mentions `UTF-8` as well. Could it be that `loadHTML` and `xpath->query` are garbling the character encoding somewhere or maybe wikipedea source is not utf-8?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with phpMyAdmin. Don't look there. Just delete all your stored data, set the charset, and double check that your columns have the right charset too. Make sure you set the connection charset when you insert the data as well when you select

Comment: Hello again, I did delete everything and I use `set_charset('utf8mb4')` in the function which returns me the `$conn` itself. More importantly, I found where the data is mangled. Please see the edit section in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Using any encode/decode is a symptom of misconfiguration.

When you connect to mysql, you tell it what encoding is being used in the *client*.

When you declare the tables, you specify how to store things.  `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` is often the best.

Please provide `SELECT HEX(col), col ...` for a sample.  (You cannot trust what the browser displays; it tries to "fix" the encoding.  Once you have the hex, we can discuss how to repair the data.  A common problem is "double-encoding", wherein the data has been misconverted twice.

As for your current samples, there are enough inconsistencies that I cannot deduce what went wrong:

```
&nbsp; ->  That is represented as hex 80 by some word processors, not by HTML.
-  --> this is a plain dash; it is never mangled.  Perhaps you have an n-dash or m-dash?
€  --> mangles to "â‚¬" via "Mojibake" through latin1;
       did you omit the "SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK" that looks like a comma??
ευρώ  --> ÎµÏ…ÏÏŽ via "Mojibake" through latin1;
```

More on Mojibake and other common manglings:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: I did a sample `SELECT HEX(col), col ...` and it returned everything in utf8 encoding which was shown correctly in the browser.  I got `2D2D2D2D  E282ACCEB5CF81CF85CF8E` for `---- €ερυώ`. I think the culprit is `xpath` or `DOMDocument`. I will get back to you with hex values on my main page where I see the actual bug.

Comment: The problem with the main page is that the `$result` of `mysqli::query("SELECT HEX(col)")` is being fed into `htmlspecialchars`, `loadHTML` and `saveHTML`. So feeding them with hex codes give me error. Let me find a way out.

Comment: Actualy `SELECT ... FROM ..` your table.  This is to see what is in the table.

Comment: I did perform it as `SELECT ... FROM ...` please see my **edit** in the question, I found the bug point which mangles the data.

Comment: `â€“` is Mojibake for "En dash".