# How do I prevent DomDocument from messing up with text?

Tags: php, html, laravel, domdocument

I am aiming to replace the anchor text in anchor tags of given text block with the title of the page the `href` attribute points to.

That is my html contains -

```
"This is <a href="https://www.example.com">www.example.com</a>"
```

I'd like to replace it with -

```
"This is <a href="https://www.example.com">Example Domain</a>"
```

Here's my PHP Code -

```
$domDocument = new \DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($text, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_NOERROR);
$domDocument->formatOutput = true;
$links = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('a');

// Step 3: Iterate on Each Link
foreach($links as $link)
{
// Step 4: Extract the href attribute from the link
$href = $link->getAttribute('href');

// Step 5: Using the extracted href, fetch the page title
$title = $this->fetchPageTitle($href);

// Step 8: Replace the existing anchor text with page title
$link->nodeValue = $title;

return $domDocument->saveHTML();

}

private function fetchPageTitle($url) :string
{
// Step 6: Fetch the contents of the page
$page_html = Http::get($url)->body();

// Step 7: Initiate a new DomDocument Object and exract page title
$pageDocument = new \DOMDocument();
$pageDocument->loadHTML($page_html, LIBXML_NOERROR);
$title = $pageDocument->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
return $title;
}
```

While this code works, it produces garbled text for some of the text.

That is the text:
`Settings → Apple → Tag`

Is reformatted to
`Settings â†’ Apple â†’ Tag`.

and `We'll` gets reformatted to `Weâ€™ll`

How do I make fix this issue?

Comment: It looks like variables that you use for replacements (e.g. `$title`) are in a different enconding than your HTML. Try using [mb_detect_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) on your HTML, replacement values and end result to check whether they actually match

Comment: Why is there a `return` in your `foreach` loop? Why is this code not indented?

Comment: And see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly

Comment: Sorry about the indentation. I realised the error with return statement and fixed it. It only prevented from processing the second link. Looks like this does the job: `$domDocument->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_NOERROR);`