# DomDocument not showing special chars (UTF printing)

Tags: php, laravel, dom, domdocument

I have a file writed in french language and I want to load it with DomDocument to parse it

```
$this->doc = new \DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$url = $this->file_get_contents_utf8('/file.html');

$array = Array();
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

@$this->doc->loadHTML($url);
$str = $this->doc->saveHTML($this->doc);

$xpath = new \DOMXpath($this->doc);
```

I saved the file with UTF8 and Tried to load it by forcing UTF-8 but it do not shows special chars like the accents

`Mairie d'Amb**Ã©ri**`

should be :

`Mairie d'Ambé...`

Comment: I explain the issue with `DOMDocument` using ISO-8859-1 character encoding by default and how modern frameworks use a workaround to output UTF-8 in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76196866/1456201

Comment: You didn't show us what `file_get_contents_utf8` does, which seems kind of important.